# How can I get TeXShop to pick up the right font, and sharply?

Tags: fonts, texshop

I am running TeXShop on a Mac, and formatting a document for Electronic Communications in Probability.  I have used their tex source to produce their sample document, available in step 1 [here](http://ecp.ejpecp.org/about/submissions#authorGuidelines).  I should get the top version, but I get the the bottom version instead.

So even though I have ejpecp.cls and the fonts in the same folder as the sample file, TeXShop is not using the right font, and is doing something that makes everything fuzzy.  How can I get TeXShop to produce a sharp version of this document, and using the right font?

[image: version from website]

[image: version I produced]

Comment: The sample file works as expected for me, with MacTeX 2013 as TeX distribution and TeXShop as front end. In particular, the Bera fonts installed in MacTeX, which are required by the `ejpecp`class, are found and used. Which TeX Distribution are you using? Caution, TeXShop is no (La)TeX distribution, only a graphical front end to (La)TeX with a text editor and a previewer.

Comment: How is this related to texshop? Texshop has nothing to do with which fonts are used in your latex document. Please give some more information about what you are trying to do and preferably a minimal example

Comment: @fpast, thanks for the clarification.  Apparently my installation of TeXShop uses the TeXLive distribution.  Once I realized this, I launched the TeXLive utility and then some automatic updates and an installation of the bera package there solved the problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is solved by an update to software.